# Binding for in clause from inside snowflake procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to execute a query

```
select * 
from table 
where column1 in (?)
```

where the value of `?` is a java script array object. How can I bind this array to a clause value?

I am looking a cleaner way available out of the box from snowflake, instead of preparing the in clause value by iterating the array and building the string.

Comment: In javascript if you have an array to can `.join(‘,’)` but you will also make each thing string presenting safe. Which is the thing you want to avoid. So this is not really the quick answer you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind a Javascript array object as currently only Javascript variables of type **number**, **string** and **SfDate** can be bound.

For more information see this [link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html#binding-variables).